# INTERSECTION in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to find the intersection in 2 queris in SQL and I am using INTERSECTION but when I try it on the command the query shows no result when I know there is a row that falls into that category. 
The question is the follow:
Find the full names of the students who have taken both CIS course and History course
This is my code:

```
SELECT student.sid
FROM student
JOIN registration 
ON registration.sid = student.sid
JOIN course 
ON registration.crn = course.crn
WHERE dept= "CIS" 

INTERSECT

SELECT student.sid 
FROM student
JOIN registration 
ON registration.sid = student.sid
JOIN course 
ON registration.crn = course.crn
WHERE dept = "HIS";
```

Comment: *" have to find the intersection in 2 queris in SQL and I am using INTERSECTION but when I try it on the command the query shows no result when I know there is a row that falls into that category"* This should give a syntax error on MySQL not a empty result  ... So you sure you are using MySQL to me it feels more you are using SQL Server (MSSQL) instead ...

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
SELECT fName, lName
FROM student
JOIN registration 
ON registration.sid = student.sid
JOIN course 
ON registration.crn = course.crn
WHERE dept= "CIS" 

AND student.sid IN

(SELECT student.sid 
FROM student
JOIN registration 
ON registration.sid = student.sid
JOIN course 
ON registration.crn = course.crn
WHERE dept = "HIS");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `EXISTS`

```
SELECT student.sid 
FROM student JOIN registration ON registration.sid = student.sid 
JOIN course ON registration.crn = course.crn WHERE dept= "CIS"
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT student.sid FROM student JOIN registration ON registration.sid = student.sid JOIN course ON registration.crn = course.crn WHERE dept = "HIS");
```